# Theano gradients failing over scan operation

Tags: python, gradient, theano, recurrent-neural-network

Implementing deep networks in theano gives me precise control over my layers from the ground up. I know it's no longer supported but it appears to me there is still active use (from me at least :->). Anyway, I noticed some behavior related to gradients calculation through a scan operation.

I have the following inner function (part of a RNN inner iteration step, I can provide if nec.):

```
    def iter_step(x_step, h):
        ...

        return hidden, obj, est
```

I have a set of parameters `h_params`, `o_params`, `e_params` that I use to compute gradients:

```
h, o, e = iter_step(x_step, h)
hidden_grads = T.grad(T.sum(h), h_params)
obj_grads = T.grad(T.sum(o), o_params)
est_grads = T.grad(T.sum(est), e_params)
```

everything is fine. I add a scan operation

```
[h_n, obj_n, x_n], _ = theano.scan(
    fn=iter_step,
    sequences=[x],
    outputs_info=[T.as_tensor_variable(np.zeros(model.h_shape), model.h.dtype),
                  None,
                  None],
    )
```

Evaluation is fine, but computing gradients on the same parameters is now a problem:

```
# Works
h_n0 = theano.function([], h_n)()
# Fails
h_n_grads = T.grad(T.sum(h_n), h_params)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NullTypeGradError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-0d7c8a65d265> in <module>
----> 1 h_n_grads = T.grad(T.sum(h_n), h_params)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py in grad(cost, wrt, consider_constant, disconnected_inputs, add_names, known_grads, return_disconnected, null_gradients)
    609             if null_gradients == 'raise':
    610                 raise NullTypeGradError("tensor.grad encountered a NaN. " +
--> 611                                         rval[i].type.why_null)
    612             else:
    613                 assert null_gradients == 'return'

NullTypeGradError: tensor.grad encountered a NaN. This variable is Null because the grad method for input 4 (Subtensor{int64}.0) of the for{cpu,scan_fn} op is mathematically undefined. Depends on a shared variable
```

Why is this? I have not been able to debug yet - graph is not disconnected, unrolling scan by hand gives good gradients. The gradient calculations should carry through the scan operation. If gradients on h (1st output of iter_step) can be calculated, why not on the analogous output of the scan?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved. `iter_step` above contained a sampling step along the lines of

```
def sample(self, mu, logSigma):
    global SEED
    srng = T.shared_randomstreams.RandomStreams(seed=SEED)
    dev = srng.normal((self.batch_size, self.n_latent[-1]))
    z = mu + T.exp(0.5 * logSigma) * dev
    return z
```

Gradients through this calculation do not survive through the `scan` operation. Separating out all the parametric dependencies in sample still didn't work. What finally worked was creating the deviates in `dev` and passing it in as one of the `non_sequences` in scan, as in

```
    [h_n, obj, x],inner_updates = theano.scan(
        fn=iter_step,
        sequences=[x_in],
        outputs_info=[T.as_tensor_variable(np.zeros(self.h_shape), self.h.dtype),
                      None,
                      None],
        non_sequences=[T.as_tensor_variable(self.srng.normal((self.batch_size, self.n_latent[-1])), self.h.dtype)],
        )
```

I have an idea why this gradients over this `scan` fail, while simple scan operations even with `randomstreams.RandomStreams` objects work. I'll take a deeper look.

Summary: Use the reparamerization trick if your distribution allows it, pass in whitened deviates, pre-parameterized as `non_sequences`. That seems to work in all cases.